# Can't get Firebase output without including Parent key

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My uni group are trying to create a simple blog app but we're having an issue with outputting the firebase data to the website without using JSON.stringify. At the moment the code we have is

```
dbRefObject.on('value',snap =>
    {
        preObject.innerText = JSON.stringify(snap.val(), null, 3);
    });
    dbRefList.on("value", function(snapshot)
    {
        var newPost = snapshot.val();

    dbRefList.on("child_added", function(newPost,pre)
        {
        newchild=newPost.val();
        ulList.innerHTML = "<pre>" + "Title: "+ newchild.Title +
        "\n"+"Message: "+ newchild.Message +
        "\n"+ "Posted: "+ newchild.Posted +"</pre>";
        });
```

the output for the preObject.innerText is.

```
   {
   "Posts": {
      "-KfXaHa8MKi4Qzsro3Hk": {
         "Message": "out with friends",
         "Posted": "Date: 18/3/2017 @ 18:6:13",
         "Title": "time out"
      },
      "-KfZ3r08lhIuEM9mb5GV": {
         "Message": "this is a test",
         "Posted": "Date: 19/3/2017 @ 0:59:24",
         "Title": "testing"
      },
      "-KfZY8zgUDJU_SooEvEO": {
         "Message": "03:11 am and this is kind of working.",
         "Posted": "Date: 19/3/2017 @ 3:11:46",
         "Title": "the time is now"
      },
      "-KfZiAijlWNU6-1RGdh9": {
         "Message": "The time is now 03:59 and things are coming good finally.",
         "Posted": "Date: 19/3/2017 @ 3:59:57",
         "Title": "Latest Progress"
      },
      "-KfZrtZU4pkgejOQ8N78": {
         "Message": "Ok time is 04:42 going to my bed.",
         "Posted": "Date: 19/3/2017 @ 4:42:24",
         "Title": "Final Post"
      },
      "-Kf_H-Lg2KOIjtOdALEf": {
         "Message": "5676576756575",
         "Posted": "Date: 19/3/2017 @ 6:36:27",
         "Title": "5675675"
      }
   }
}
```

We want the code to output the child of every Key without displaying the key. I'm struggling to find anything on the firebase docs to help with this so thought I'd ask, Hopefully I've provided enough information, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the posts doing things with each one:

```
var obj = snap.val();
for (var key in obj.Posts) {
  var post = obj[key];
  console.log(post.Title + ", " + post.Message + ", " + post.Posted);
}
```

(the variable `key` contains the alphanumeric key should you need it)